# Ubuntu 18.04 has purple border on the bottom, and right side of the screen, sometimes

Tags: nvidia

As I'm writing this on Firefox, the purple border is not there. Only Firefox does not show the border, as far as I'm aware.

[This is what it looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHYrg.png)

The cursor still appears in it, but the wallpaper doesn't cover it, and appears to be exactly 2 pixels wide.

I first noticed when I shifted 'focus' from a full screen game, to just the desktop using the super key.

I have a 1080Ti and I am using the proprietary Nvidia driver, 430.

16gb ram, Intel Xeon V2, 8gb swap.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the error, just turn off the zoom feature from Universal Access menu in settings. The purple border just disappeared.

Comment: Thanks!  That fixed it.